# Thread-Safe Properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, concurrency, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a class that has many properties that are `Integer` and `Single`. I would like to use the class in a multi-threaded way such that the properties can be used as accumulators (the class is the foundation of a reporting scheme). So I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Public Class ReportTotals
    Property Count As Integer
    Property Total As Single
    Property Tax As Single
    Property Shipping As Single
    Property ItemsSold As Integer

    Public Function GetReport() As String
    ...
    End Function
End Class

Public Function BuildReportData As ReportTotals

    Dim myReport As New ReportTotals
    With myReport
        Parallel.ForEach(UserSales, Sub(userSale)
                .Count += 1
                .Total += userSale.Total
                .Tax += userSale.Tax
                .Shipping += userSale.Shipping
                .ItemsSold += userSale.ItemsSold

                'more complicated stuff and property assignments

            End Sub)
    End With
End Function
```

Based on my research I know that `Integer` and `Single` are atomic, but I'm not sure if that extends to integers that are part of a class. I don't want to assume because multi-threaded bugs could come up later and bite me.

UPDATE: Apparently, `Single` isn't thread safe, so I have to use a lock on that one, but what about `Integer`?

Comment: Integer assigments are atomic but `.Count += 1` is not. `Interlocked.Increment` can perform an atomic operation but if you want to make sure two increment operations to be atomic you can use `Lock`

Comment: Your code looks like you won't gain much from parallelizing it (assuming it's your real code). If each iteration is this simple, I think it's likely that the parallelized version will be actually slower, due to overhead.

Comment: Each iteration isn't simple at all. In each iteration there are several LINQ statements and mathematical processing taking place. I registered nearly a 50% increase in speed just be doing the above (of course, that isn't counting for thread safety).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like what you want is [an overload of `Parallel.ForEach()` that works with local state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486.aspx).

In the `localInit` delegate, you would create a new instance of `ReportTotals` and in `localFinally` you would add the values of the local `ReportTotals` to the global one, under a lock.

Comment: While I think this pattern made my code more difficult to read, it is the correct way to implement this as opposed to what I [did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16157588/271351); and it is probably a little faster. It was good to learn this new pattern and it is great that I don't have to change my class (save for the lock object) to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) to increment integers in an atomic fashion, even if they are class members.

Comment: But you can't do that with properties.

Comment: Per the sample code, there is no reason to define them as properties as opposed to public fields -- They are publicly accessible, there is no special get/set logic.

Comment: As a matter of personal preference, I would implement private Integer members and use Interlocked.Increment and public property getters to avoid allowing any other code to modify the value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [SyncLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx) is what you are looking for.

```
 Public Sub sale(s As String)
     SyncLock _lock
          //'thread safe code'
     End SyncLock
 End Sub

 Public Function BuildReportData as ReportTotals

 Dim myReport As New ReportTotals
 With myReport
     Parallel.ForEach(UserSales, sale(userSale))

 End Function
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you enclose the whole method in a `SyncLock`, there is no reason to use `Parallel.ForEach()`, since it won't actually run in parallel.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for my wrong answer! I'll leave it here so maybe someone will learn from my wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

What I've decided to do, at least until someone has a better idea, is to create lots of `ReportTotals` objects in the `Parallel.ForEach` routine and put them all into a `ConcurrentBag`. Then, after the `Parallel.ForEach` statement concludes I use a regular `For Each` statement to accumulate all the values in the `ReportTotals` objects in the `ConcurrentBag` into a new `ReportTotals` object that I then return.

So I'm doing something like this:

```
Public Class ReportTotals
    Property Count As Integer
    Property Total As Single
    Property Tax As Single
    Property Shipping As Single
    Property ItemsSold As Integer

    Public Function GetReport() As String
    ...
    End Function
End Class

Public Function BuildReportData As ReportTotals

    Dim myReport As New ReportTotals
    Dim myReports As New ConcurrentBag(Of ReportTotals)

    Paralle.ForEach(UserSales, Sub(userSale)
            Dim workingReport As New ReportTotals
            With workingReport
                .Count += 1
                .Total += userSale.Total
                .Tax += userSale.Tax
                .Shipping += userSale.Shipping
                .ItemsSold += userSale.ItemsSold

                'more complicated stuff and property assignments

            End With
        End Sub)

    For Each report In myReports 
        With myReport
            .Count += report.Count
            .Total += report.Total
            .Tax += report.Tax
            .Shipping += report.Shipping
            .ItemsSold += report.ItemsSold
        End With
    Next

    Return myReport
End Function
```